# Can you link an image field to a link field by 'Manage display'?

Tags: 7, entities, media, navigation

I have a content type with two fields: image and link. I'd like the image to display linked to the link field. I'm happy to do that myself programmatically, I'm just wondering if there's a module that lets you do this directly from the *Manage display* screen (ie zero code).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using [Linked Field](http://drupal.org/project/linked_field) and [Token](http://drupal.org/project/token) module, you can easily do this by checking ***"Link this field"***, and entering the appropriate token of your [Link](http://drupal.org/project/link) field.

Here is an example:

**Destination:**

```
[node:field-test-link:url]
```

**Title:**

```
[node:field-test-link:title]
```

[image: Link this field + Image field]

Comment: I was hoping it might come along, many thanks for the info!

Comment: you're welcome, I'm glad I could help, Andy!